# Want to Add View Controllers to Tabbar items

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, tabbar, xcode10

Hi i am currently working on an project which requires two tab bars one at top and second at bottom i have added these tab bars but the problem is i am stuck with navigating between viewcontrollers using those tab bars item. using tabbar

```
let tabbar1 = UITabBar() //Note that tabbar height is fixed to 49
view.addSubview(tabbar1)

tabbar1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabbar1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

let contacts = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.contacts, tag: 100)
let bookmarks = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 101)
tabbar1.setItems([contacts, bookmarks], animated: false)

let tabbar2 = UITabBar() //Note that tabbar height is fixed to 49
view.addSubview(tabbar2)

tabbar2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabbar2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

let downloads = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.downloads, tag: 103)
let favorites = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.favorites, tag: 104)
tabbar2.setItems([downloads, favorites], animated: false)
```

Comment: Use UITabBarController. Do not put a tab bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: but adding two tab bars is our requirement and UITabbarController is working in our scenario

Comment: It doesnt make sence to use two tab bars in one ViewController. As @matt said you should use a UITabBarController for your Navigation and a Segment for the other thing you want to do